# is The Ruby Programming Language book still valid in ruby 2.2.2?

Tags: ruby, ruby-2.2

I am learning ruby.  I was wondering if the [The Ruby Programming Language](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596516177) book is still valid in ruby 2.2.2 even though the book is written for ruby 1.8 and 1.9?

Comment: most of the things are still relevant. just read the book. then check what's new in ruby.

Comment: Okay thanks, do you know some of the major updates that i should be aware of? :)

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Ruby-1-9-2-0-Programmers/dp/1937785491

Comment: It may be a bit long in the the tooth, but it's still a great book.

Comment: I've removed the request for a book recommendation, since off-site recommendations are off topic for SO.  The rest of the question is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The Well Grounded Rubyist](http://manning.com/black3) has been published more recently than that, and covers Ruby 2.1. There weren't any large changes between 2.1 and 2.2, so that book should cover everything you need to know.

Comment: I've have seen one of your talks on Youtube, that's pretty cool :O